# Customize behavior of BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, navigation, bottomnavigationview

I want to pop-up a fragment on click on different tab within `BottomNavigationView`.

I have three tabs in `BottomNavigationView` which 2nd is made as a start destination. On this 2nd tab I can search for some item and data from backend will be shown on another fragment within this stack, in other words:

```
A - B - C (origin state)

    D
A - B - C (state after search has been performed)
```

On back button click this fragment will be removed to the origin state  `A - B - C`, but if after search user clicks on another tab A or C, the stack will remain D fragment and D fragment will be shown after user return back on B tab.

Navigation supports in xml `popUpInclusive` option, but default navigation of `BottomNavigationView` doesn't define navigation action in xml - it supports it out-of-the-box. At least I haven't found how to override this behaviour.
I might listen for navigation changes over `OnItemViewSelectedListener`, but it is not clear how to proceed with it next. Some others [solutions to use fragmentManager.replace()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68674323/3649629) looks ugly. `navigateUp()` looks better, but I haven't managed yet to apply it right to this scenario and it also causes concerns regarding right way to deal with navigation component.

What is a right way to achieve this behaviour? I want to my search fragment to be popped up from the stack when user navigate to the different tab.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/navigation_dashboard">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
        android:name="ru.home.government.screens.deputies.DeputiesFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_deputies"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_deputies">
        <argument
            android:name="EXTRA_NO_BOTTOM_VIEW"
            app:argType="boolean"
            android:defaultValue="false" />

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_home_to_navigation_dashboard"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_dashboard"
            app:popUpTo="@+id/navigation_home"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />

    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_dashboard"
        android:name="ru.home.government.screens.laws.main.LawsMainFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_laws"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_laws" >

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_dashboard_to_lawsFilteredFragment"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_laws_filtered"
            />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_dashboard_to_navigation_home"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_home"
            app:popUpTo="@+id/navigation_dashboard"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true"
            />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_dashboard_to_navigation_notifications"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_notifications"
            app:popUpTo="@+id/navigation_dashboard"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true"
            />

    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_notifications"
        android:name="ru.home.government.screens.tracker.TrackerFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_tracker"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_tracker">

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_notifications_to_navigation_dashboard"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_dashboard"
            app:popUpTo="@+id/navigation_home"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />

    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_laws_filtered"
        android:name="ru.home.government.screens.laws.filter.LawsFilteredFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_search"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_law_filtered">

        <argument
            android:name="EXTRA_KEY"
            app:argType="string"
            android:defaultValue="false" />

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_laws_filtered_to_navigation_home"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_home"
            app:popUpTo="@+id/navigation_dashboard"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_laws_filtered_to_navigation_notifications"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_notifications"
            app:popUpTo="@+id/navigation_dashboard"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />

    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

Comment: How you are showing your fragments? If you are using fragment navigation you can set it up the xml way you described above, I assume that you have some code that handles bottomNavView items click, there you can use appropriate action of fragment navigation

Comment: Fragments are defined in ```nav_graph``` in xml file, but navigation between tabs is handled automatically by ```BottomNavigationView```. Therefor your assumption regarding  bottomNavView items click is not correct and I do not even see a way to override it.

Comment: @Rob, I updated post with ```nav_graph.xml```

Comment: created a similar project and test the code in answer it works - please check @Gleichmut

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, I have created a test project with 4 fragments like in your case, there is only other thing with back press, and you should handle it also, I will provide that code at the end

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/navigation_dashboard">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
        android:name="ru.home.government.screens.deputies.DeputiesFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_deputies"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_deputies">
        <argument
            android:name="EXTRA_NO_BOTTOM_VIEW"
            app:argType="boolean"
            android:defaultValue="false" />

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_home_to_navigation_dashboard"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_dashboard" />

    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_dashboard"
        android:name="ru.home.government.screens.laws.main.LawsMainFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_laws"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_laws" >

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_dashboard_to_lawsFilteredFragment"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_laws_filtered"
            />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_dashboard_to_navigation_home"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_home" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_dashboard_to_navigation_notifications"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_notifications"
            app:popUpTo="@+id/navigation_dashboard"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true"
            />

    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_notifications"
        android:name="ru.home.government.screens.tracker.TrackerFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_tracker"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_tracker">

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_notifications_to_navigation_dashboard"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_dashboard"
            app:popUpTo="@+id/navigation_home"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />

    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_laws_filtered"
        android:name="ru.home.government.screens.laws.filter.LawsFilteredFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_search"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_law_filtered">

        <argument
            android:name="EXTRA_KEY"
            app:argType="string"
            android:defaultValue="false" />

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_laws_filtered_to_navigation_home"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_home" />

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_laws_filtered_to_navigation_notifications"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_notifications" />

    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

NOTE*** DO NOT DO THIS LAST PART IF YOU WANT TO NAVIGATE FROM NOTIFICATIONS TO HOME ON BACK PRESSED otherwise do this steps

and the back press handling

define a backPressedCallback

```
private val backPressedCallback = object : OnBackPressedCallback(enabled = true) {
    override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
        if (navController.currentDestination?.id == R.id.navigation_notifications) {
            navController.navigate(R.id.action_navigation_notifications_to_navigation_dashboard)
        }
    }
}
```

register it

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val navView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav_bar)

    navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
        backPressedCallback.isEnabled = destination.id == R.id.navigation_notifications // enable back press custom handling only when notifications screen is on 
    }
    onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this, backPressedCallback)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Althought it doesn't fully solve the issue: a. on switch to ```C``` tab, ```D``` fragment remains on top of ```B```. b. the wrong tab is highlighted. You mind consider easier to check code against my codebase and do a pull request  https://github.com/Gelassen/government-rus, branch ```bugfix/navigation-in-search```